Prove $\bar{A}$ is compact if $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ bounded, with the usual metric.
My attempt:
Let $(x_n)\in\bar{A}$. We'll show it has a subsequence $(x_{kn})$ converging to some $x\in\bar{A}$.
For all $x_n$ there is a $(y_m)\in\ A:y_m\to\ x_n,m\to\infty$
So for every $ε>0$ there is $m_0(ε)\in\mathbb{N}$ with $|y_m-x_n|<ε$ for all $m\geq\ 
m_0$
I think maybe, if we chose $m_0(1),m_0(1/2),...,m_0(1/n)$ we could then do something with the sequence
$(z_n)\in\ A$ with $z_n=y_{m_0(1/n)}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ However, I'm confused because, from what I've written down, we can see that the sequence of $(y_n)$'s "converges" to $(x_n)$ but there is nothing to go on to get from that point to it converging to a single point in $\mathbb{R}$ even with $A$ being bounded.

Do you know that closed bounded subsets are compact ?

Independently from the fact that your approach is not conclusive, its notation is sloppy: $(y_m)m$ should be $(y{n,m})m$ (one such sequence for each $x_n$), and $m_0(ε)$ s.t. $|y_m-x_n|<ε$ for all $m\geq\ 
m_0$ should be $m_n(\varepsilon)$ s.t. $|y{n,m}-x_n|<ε$ for all $m\ge m_n(\varepsilon)$, and it is $z_n:=y_{m_n(1/n)}$ which "converges" to $x_n$ (more correctly: which is such that $|x_n-z_n|\to0$). Anyway, that is of no help indeed.

Instead, observe that since $A$ is bounded, so is $\overline A$ hence $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence, which admits therefore a converging subsequence.
